# Mysql num rows in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I need to display some ordered numbers, from 1 to 15 right before the ID, so basically, I need a new number on every new row, like this:

1. ID NAME KILLS, etc.
2. ID NAME KILLS, etc.
3. ID NAME KILLS, etc.
   ...
4. ID NAME KILLS, etc.

Here is the code, I failed with "foreach" for some reason, I got a repeating loop 15x15...

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `sc_rank` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 15',$connect) or die (mysql_error());
while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$get["id"].'</td><td>'.$get["name"].'</td><td>'.$get["kills"].'</td><td>'.$get["deaths"].'</td><td>'.$get["hd"].'</td><td>'.$get["eff"].'%</td><td>'.$get["acc"].'%</td><td>'.$get["damage"].'</td><td>'.$get["shots"].'</td><td>'.$get["hits"].'</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize a variable `$i = 1;` right before your loop, echo it and increment `$i++;` in the end of the loop body

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `sc_rank` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 15',$connect) or die (mysql_error());

$i = 1;
while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$get["id"].'</td><td>'.$get["name"].'</td><td>'.$get["kills"].'</td><td>'.$get["deaths"].'</td><td>'.$get["hd"].'</td><td>'.$get["eff"].'%</td><td>'.$get["acc"].'%</td><td>'.$get["damage"].'</td><td>'.$get["shots"].'</td><td>'.$get["hits"].'</td></tr>';

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the same... add a counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an integer to increment.

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `sc_rank` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 15',$connect) or die (mysql_error());
$i = 0;
while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $i++;
    $strDisplay  = "<tr><td>$i.</td><td>$get['id']</td>";
    $strDisplay .= "<td>$get['kills']</td><td>$get['deaths']</td>";
    $strDisplay .= "<td>$get['hd']</td><td>$get['eff']%</td>";
    $strDisplay .= "<td>$get['acc']%</td><td>$get['damage']</td>";
    $strDisplay .= "<td>$get['shots']</td><td>$get['hits']</td></tr>";

    echo $strDisplay;
}
```

Changed the formatting a bit to make it a little more readable...

Or you can alternatively use a numbered list in HTML.

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `sc_rank` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 15',$connect) or die (mysql_error());
$i = 0;
$strDisplay = "<ol>";
while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $i++;
    $strDisplay  .= "<li><tr><td>$get['id']</td>";
    $strDisplay .= "<td>$get['kills']</td><td>$get['deaths']</td>";
    $strDisplay .= "<td>$get['hd']</td><td>$get['eff']%</td>";
    $strDisplay .= "<td>$get['acc']%</td><td>$get['damage']</td>";
    $strDisplay .= "<td>$get['shots']</td><td>$get['hits']</td></tr></li>";
}

$strDisplay .= "</ol>";
echo $strDisplay;
```

The numbered list method may not be the best method within a table.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could try iterating with a for loop, using the [mysql_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) php function, something like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `sc_rank` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 15',$connect) or die (mysql_error());

for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($sql); $i++) {
    $get = mysql_result($sql,$i);
    echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$get["id"].'</td><td>'.$get["name"].'</td><td>'.$get["kills"].'</td><td>'.$get["deaths"].'</td><td>'.$get["hd"].'</td><td>'.$get["eff"].'%</td><td>'.$get["acc"].'%</td><td>'.$get["damage"].'</td><td>'.$get["shots"].'</td><td>'.$get["hits"].'</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `sc_rank` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 15', $connect) or die(mysql_error());
        $max = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        for($i > 0; $i <= $max; $i++) {
            while($get = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$get["id"].'</td><td>'.$get["name"].'</td><td>'.$get["kills"].'</td><td>'.$get["deaths"].'</td><td>'.$get["hd"].'</td><td>'.$get["eff"].'%</td><td>'.$get["acc"].'%</td><td>'.$get["damage"].'</td><td>'.$get["shots"].'</td><td>'.$get["hits"].'</td></tr>'; 
            }
        }
```

This one should be fine too:)

Comment: of course no. You have **2 nested loops**. Why do you need **2** loops?